# Авторизация при работе с БД

Tags: delphi, база-данных, mysql

Если есть в программе авторизация по таблице из бд Mysql, как в программе (Delphi) в дальнейшем ассоциировать пользователя, например, для того, чтобы создать тригер "кто создавал, апдейтил эту запись". Подскажите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я, для своих программ, создавал HEAP-таблицу где ассоциировал пользователя с идентификатором подключения к MySQL ( функция `CONNECTION_ID()` ). Пользователь авторизовался - в таблицу добавили запись, вышел - записть удалили. Для защиты от снятия процесса программы, или сбоя в программе, при запуске удаляются "мертвые" сессии.

Чтобы узнать список активных подключений:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST
```

Соответственно, чтобы в триггере узнать от имени какого пользователя выполняется операция, нужно обратиться к таблице сессий и получить информация о активной сессии по `CONNECTION_ID()`.

Comment: Спасибо, вот это правильный подход.

Comment: Пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Функции `USER(), CURRENT_USER()`.

Comment: вход в саму БД происходит под одним пользователем, при входе в программу происходит сверка по таблице. Я не совсем понял твой ответ)

Comment: Тогда это не авторизация а эрзац. А значит вся работа ложится на прикладную программу

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, подключение к БД идет от одного имени, причем не важно, кто вошел в систему (Вася, Петя  и тд), тогда скорее всего триггерами (я с ними мало знаком и точно утверждать не буду) наверно не получится, потому как триггер работает на сервере БД и он не знает, кто именно вошел. Тогда можно сделать встроенные функции - и передавать туда имя вошедшего в программу (Вася Петя и тд), она и будет писать логи. Как-то так.